# How to Pass HashCode of a Control as a CommandParameter in WPF XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hashcode

I'm having a DataGridColumnHeader Sytle, in that I'm having a Button for Filtering. I need to Pass the Button HashCode as a Command Parameter

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" x:Key="DummyFilterDataGridColumnHeader">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
              <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.FilterPopUpCommand, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                  AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                  <Button.CommandParameter>
                      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverterKey}">
                          <Binding RelativeSource="{ RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                     AncestorType={x:Type cust:DataGrid}}" />
                          <Binding Path="Column" 
                                   RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" />
                          <Binding Path="HashCode"  />
                      </MultiBinding>
                  </Button.CommandParameter>
              </Button>
          </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

> Note: My Requirement is to pass HashCode only from the XAML not in the
>   C# extraction from a Button Control.

Comment: By HashCode, you  mean the one that GetHashCode() method returns ?

Answer (score 1):

Since the only way to get the `HashCode` of the `Button` is through the `GetHashCode()` method, i suggest you to pass a reference of the Button itself to the Command like this :

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                    <Button x:Name="Btn" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.FilterPopUpCommand, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                              AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                        <Button.CommandParameter>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MultiValueConverterKey}">
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{ RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                                 AncestorType={x:Type cust:DataGrid}}" />
                                <Binding Path="Column" 
                               RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}" />
                                <Binding ElementName="Btn" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Button.CommandParameter>
                    </Button>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

In the `MultivalueConverter`, extract the Hash code and pass it to the Command :

```
 public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values==null)            
            return null;
        var hashCode = (values[2] as Button).GetHashCode();
       //the rest of your code 
    }
```

Comment: I already implemented like this. But I need the implementation in the XAML Level not in the C# Code... Kindly assist me...

Comment: Tha's all what you need to change in your ControlTemplate in order to pass the Button's HashCode to the Command, as far as i see, there are no further changes required!, what problem you are facing when applying the above style ?

Comment: My Requirement is to pass HashCode only from the XAML not in the C# extraction from a Button Control.

Comment: well, you simply can't, since there no property in the button that hold a value called Hashcode, the hash code needs to be calculated each time you wan't it, 

if you insiste of geting that property (i don't see why you wan't to skip the call for tha GetHashCode method since it offers the same result), you need to define a custom button control (or a user control), define a dependency property that will get you the HashCode (of course through the GetHashCode method) as a property, and that's seems to me like an extra necessary work